# How can I confirm that my Jekyll is installed well?

Tags: github, jekyll

This is my test page. I'm on windows 8.1

http://hypergroups.github.io/

```
 jekyll --server --auto
```

this is an deprecated command.
And I've tried serve, but maybe I'm not right, and maybe I haven't configure the enviroment well?

[image]

[image]

I want to make this be successful

`http://localhost:4000/hypergroups/index.html`

[image]

Comment: What do you see when you run `jekyll --safe --trace`?

Comment: @RobertKenny deprecated information, see the picture added.

Comment: Sorry meant `jekyll serve --safe --trace`

Comment: What is in your `_config.yml`?

Comment: @RobertKenny I‘ve added something: permalink: /:year/:month/:day/:title.html

auto: true
markdown: rdiscount

Comment: What about just `http://localhost:4000`? It should be serving pages from the `_site` sub directory from the directory you started Jekyll from.

Comment: @RobertKenny I just be successful after trying http://127.0.0.1:4000/, http://localhost:4000 is Ok, thanks.

Comment: @RobertKenny If I encounter other problems, then glad to ask you. :)

Comment: Great, I'll add it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your `_config.yml` isn't empty.

Also Jekyll will serve pages @ `http://localhost:4000` from the `_site` sub directory of the directory you run Jekyll from.

Comment: Hi, I've installed one theme, however, the page width is too narrow, do you know how to make it wider? [here is my page](http://hypergroups.github.io/2013/09/02/WordList-2013-9-2/), and the word-cloud image is also shown a little narrow.

Comment: If you look at you template you will see a `<div class="row">` with two `div`'s inside. One `<div class="span8">` and one `<div class="span4">` these control the width of the columns. The total should add up to 12. So a `<div class="span10">` with a`<div class="span2">` will open up the content and shrink the the sidebar.

Comment: Thanks, it works, I changed "span8" to "span12" in the `page.html` of the theme.